# How to download a file from CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm working on a College Application project.

I want to ask how to download the files that previously uploaded by user.

Here's the clear view :

1. User will upload the files.
2. Controller will handle the request and save the name of the files into database.
3. How admin can download the file ???

I try to access the `localhost/system/files/upload.doc` but doesn't got any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using Media views: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1094/Media-Views

These will allow you to go to a path and load the database information about the file and then present the file with necessary download headers to the user.

Comment: a little ask Barry. I store the location of the files in database.. which is "academic_certificated/education1_transript_200.jpg".. how to get this thing into media view.. I already try to substring the necessary things and put it in media view.. but got no luck. It said

"Error: The requested address '/applications/getCert1/200' was not found on this server."

Answer (score 0):

yes use media views. They are the best way to keep your files from being publically accessible. So an admin can be "Served" the file and others can not get to them .

You can rename the file and things like that as you serve it to the user as well. Very nice feature of cake.